# colorbox throwing an error even after library is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Trying to call colorbox even after the library is loaded...

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: 'results.cfm?tab=updates',
            data: dataString,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                var xData = $("#hidden-div > pre").html(data);
                $.colorbox({inline:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: xData});
                }
            });
        });
```

trying to load the results in the div defined at the bottom with id of hidden-div and having pre tag after it.

every time i am getting an error colorbox is undefined, not sure why

Comment: `with id of hidden-div and having pre tag after it` *after* it or *nested in* it?  These two selectors are different.

Comment: If `$.colorbox` is undefined, then it does not exist on the `jQuery` namespace.

Comment: @Taplar  the PRE tag it is inside that #hidden-dev element

Comment: Ok, in that case if it is a direct child of the div then that selector is accurate.  So saying "having pre tag after it" is inaccurate in terms of the DOM structure.

Comment: But back to your original question.  What is the loading order of your jquery and your colorbox plugin and this script block?

Comment: jquery first, then colorbox and then the other scipts like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok, so check your developer tools network console and verify all those files are being imported correctly, and check your console for errors as well

Comment: ok, yep just checked, it works very well

Comment: Do you have any other javascript imports any where else on the page?  Are you importing jQuery again any where else pass those imports?

Comment: no, that is only place where jquery is loaded

Comment: Ok, then something you have told us is inaccurate.  If that is the load order you have, and they all loaded successfully, and you are not loading jQuery again after loading the plugin, `colorbox` would indeed exist on the jQuery namespace.

Comment: and why would i lie, to test someone, there might be a different way to try it and if colorbox has initiated or not

Comment: I'm not suggesting you are doing it intentionally.  I'm simply stating if all those things were true, it would exist.  So since that is not the case, something is not what it has been said it is.